# Tell ESS to use a different R program when on a Tramp remote session

Tags: tramp, ess, r, remote

I'm trying to configure ESS to use a different R program path when I'm on a remote session. Now, every time I ssh into the hpc cluster I use, I set the variable inferior-ess-R-program to /weird/path/to/R to make ESS open up a remote R session, but I'd like to figure out how to this automatically. I use R on my local machine via ESS as well, so changing the variable permanently it not an option. Thanks!

Comment: Is R on the remote machine on the $PATH for that machine? If so, the process described in the ESS manual, [(ess) ESS processes on Remote Computers](https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#ESS-processes-on-Remote-Computers) should work

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which Tramp version you use. But in the more recent versions, you can set connection-local variables. Check the Tramp manual for details.

Comment: Thanks - I use the most recent version. I've been consulting the manual, but somehow I'm yet to make it work. I'll try a bit more. Thanks!