# How to use connection-local-set-profiles to set inferior-ess-r-program when on using ESS over TRAMP?

Tags: tramp, ess, ssh, remote

This is a similar question to [this other](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61039/tell-ess-to-use-a-different-r-program-when-on-a-tramp-remote-session?newreg=491dff62b9e040b3a9c68003d5b25ef5) that remains unanswered.

I am doing some work in the R language with the ess package on emacs on a remote computer to which I connect via tramp/ssh. The remote computer is on my `.ssh/config` named `dev_node`. ESS is supposed to be able to attach to a running R process. To launch this R process, it uses the variable inferior-ess-r-program.

I would like emacs to know that, when I am on ssh over TRAMP, the value of the variable `inferior-ess-r-program` should be  `/mnt/opt/Centos/path/to/bin/R`.

I thought that using [connection-local-variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Connection-Local-Profiles.html) would do the trick, so I tried:

```lisp
(connection-local-set-profile-variables
 'remote-R
 '((inferior-ess-r-program . "/mnt/opt/Centos/path/to/bin/R")))

(connection-local-set-profiles
 '(:application tramp :protocol "ssh" :machine "dev_node")
 'remote-R)
```

But it did not work. Ess is incapable of launching R. Also, if on eshell I do `echo $inferior-ess-r-program` I only receive R.

On the other hand, if I run

```lisp
(setq inferior-ess-r-program "/mnt/opt/Centos/path/to/bin/R")
```

ESS is able to launch a process and `echo $inferior-ess-r-program` on the eshell returns the expected value. But then this setting is not connection-specific.

Am I using connection-local-variables wrong? Is this not its intended purpose? What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Connection-local variables require, that they are set in a recent buffer. Since I don't use R and ess, it might require to understand more details of your setup. The Tramp ML <tramp-devel@gnu.org> might be a place to discuss this.